# how to template bootstrap 5 to joomla 5

Tags: joomla

I bought a bootstrap 5 template, what can I do to make the html template work on Joomla 5?

I used to create a template with html for Joomla2, now it looks quite different.

It seems to me that under Joomla2 it was easier.